# Is there a way to know when user click ok button on print dialog initiated by self.print using PHP?

Tags: php, printdialog

I need help on something.

Is there a way to know when user click ok button on print dialog box initiated by self.print using PHP? If yes, how? Thanks! If no, thank you for the answer.

Comment: If you are calling a javascript function to load the print dialog then yes. You can also do an ajax call in that function to send the server a notification.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, sir @RiggsFolly . Now that you mention it there is an event to know when the printing is done! Thanks!

Comment: Ah that event (onafterprint) only works on FF and IE. T_T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't something that would likely be able to be accomplished through PHP.  PHP is a server language and the browser doesn't typically send anything to the server when it prints.

You might be able to accomplish this with javascript or a browser plug-in but it would probably be hard to maintain and not work across all browsers.